# delete with entity manager nativequery doesnt do anything

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

Id like to allow user to delete one tag from expert entity in many to many relationship. Tags is an array list inside expert.

**My model expert:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;



    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "experts_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tags_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="experts_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>(); //constructor,getters and setters
```

**My model tag:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Expert> experts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Tag() {
    }

    public Tag(String name, List<Expert> experts) {
        this.name = name;
        this.experts = experts;
    }  //getters and setters
```

Im trying to delete with entitity manager, using a native query that deletes tag by id from the common experts_tags column.

**My tagDao method to delete:**

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteTagById(Long id) {
 
    if(id!=null){


        manager.createNativeQuery("delete from experts_tags e where tags_id="+id);
        manager.flush();


    }
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

}
```

But this method doesnt do absolutly nothing. No error, but neither delete my tag. why this?? I dunno what is happening.

Appreciate any help!!! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`executeUpdate()` is missing:

```
manager
    .createNativeQuery(...)
    .executeUpdate();
```

You could also use a JPQL query and should also use parameters:

```
manager
    .createQuery("delete from Expert e where e.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .executeUpdate();
```

No need to flush.